# How does Laravel's Session work?

Tags: laravel-4

I'm digging through the [Laravel Session module](http://laravel.com/docs/session) code, to learn how the file driver works. What confuses me is where / how the session ID is stored / persisted. I cannot find anywhere where the class `Illuminate\Session\Store` is instantiated with an `$id` (third parameter). What am I missing?

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php
Store is instantiated in this class https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Session/SessionManager.php

Comment: Are you sure that $id is even set?